Issue occur in flutter: Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes
So I am a new for flutter and also visual studio code. I try to create a shopping app for my assignment. When I want to place a video in my dart file, it occur this problem.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':video_player_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-3\02855f0591e0b53ee6ab2869fb61eb7d\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-3\02855f0591e0b53ee6ab2869fb61eb7d\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I try to adjust the version of my build.gradle but it doesn't work.
